# putting numbers in footer of \pagestyle{header}

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I like the format of \pagestyle{header}, however, I want the page number to remain in the footer.
Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside]{article}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

\section{Introduction}
Hello
\end{document}
```

This is what the result looks like:

[image]

I would like the number to remain in the footer.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `fancyhdr` this quite easy. I've put the page number into the centered footer here. If it should appear left or right use `\lfoot` or `\rfoot` then.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{headings}{%
\cfoot{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `fancyhdr` is there a way to restrict the header to just the Chapter names (even if there are section names?) I can ask another question/edit original question if it is inappropriate to post this as a comment?

Comment: @owwoow14: You've got no chapters in `article` class. Use `book` then. And yes, it's another question, actually ;-)