# `fancyhdr` to include just Chapter in header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Using `fancyhdr` is there a way to restrict the header to just the Chapter names (ignoring any section names?)

Spinning off of my previous question [here]:[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252377/putting-numbers-in-footer-of-pagestyleheader) I would like to limit the header information to just include the name of the corresponding Chapter.

I place here the MWE from the selected answer from the previous question.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{headings}{%
\cfoot{\page}
}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{introduction}
\section{description}
Hello. This is an example
\end{document}
```

In this way, the Section "Description" will NOT be in the header, only the Chapter "Introduction".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lhead[\leftmark]{}
\rhead[]{\leftmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{introduction}
\section{description}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]